# Scraping OTT platform content list

Tags: web, web-crawler, ott

How to scrape OTT streaming platforms(Netflix, Prime video, HULU, Hotstar, etc.) catalogue list with details like flixjini, justwatchit and other's do?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the above services used to offer API's to 3rd party search services to help list their content but it does seem that most now do not.

Without this you may find you have to create your own web crawler and also have accounts for every service and region you want to crawl, which may make it unviable commercially. You also probably need to check the applicable laws in any regions you want to do this.

There are some open source web crawling solutions you could look at and also engage with the community on - e.g.
:

- https://scrapy.org